# Error en mi sentencia de SQL, no me saca ningún resultado

Tags: php, sql

Estoy tratando de sacar todas los mensajes que no han sido **leído** por el usuario que esta conectado para mostrar el numero de notificaciones de mensajes no leído.

Pero por alguna razón que desconozco este no me esta sacando ningún resultado de la base de datos. Al principio creí que era un error en mi código y intente consultar mi consulta SQL en **phpMyAdmin** y me lanza el error, por esa razón creo que el error esta en mi sentencia **SQL**.

[image: Error lanzado en la consola de phpMyAdmin]

### Esto es lo que me esta mostrando en mi pantalla:

[image: Error lanzado en pantalla]

### Mi sentencia SQL:

```
<?php

 // sacar todos los usuarios registrados recientemente
 $stetament = $conexion->prepare(
    "SELECT id_messege, COUNT(id_messege) AS countNoti FROM messege WHERE view 'No' AND id_receptor = $id"
);

$stetament->execute(array());
while ($result = $stetament->fetch()) {   
    // cantidad de Productos publicados
    $noti = $row['countNoti'];
}

var_dump($noti);
```

Lo que quiero lograr como dije antes es sacar la cantidad de mensajes no leído por el usuario que esta conectado. El **ID** del usuario que esta conectado se encuentra almacenado en una variable llama `$id` y los mensajes que no han sido leído son cuando `view = 'No'`

**NOTA:** el archivo `notificacion.php` contiene el código SQL que esta arriba y la linea 14 es donde dice: `var_dump($noti);`

Comment: Tu sentencia esta incompleta, debes agrupar

Comment: Probaste con `view = 'No'`? En el `where` de tu consulta.

Comment: las dos cosas que te dicen arriba son tu error. tu sql esta mal

Comment: Creo que el problema es que `view` es una palabra resevada de mysql, intenta poner este caracter ` (backtick) antes y después de view... o sea `\`view\` = 'No'`.

Comment: @Bicho Tienes toda la razón, no se como no me fije en este error no le estaba asignado el signo de igual al campo `view`.

Comment: @Pipe Muchas gracias por el dato curioso de la palabra reservada de `view` ya he logrado solucionar el problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se base que en tu consulta de **SQL** no estas colocando la letra de igual para comprobar si `view = 'No'`.

Por otra parte como ya se te menciono en los comentario, `view` es una palabra reservada de SQL y por lo tanto debes debes de agregarla entre 2 aceptos grabes para no tener problema con tu sentencia de **SQL**